# hide controls if there is no user interaction on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building a video chat UI where I need to hide all controls except the video if there is no user interaction on the screen, and make them visible whenever there is any type of user interaction by touching, tapping, etc.

It is like any video chat in ios or android native video calls. How can we achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use GestureDetector for this one. A counter that start ticking  from 0  when a touch event is recieved.
Use the same counter check for a handler, say when the counter value equals a predefined value for e.g 15 seconds. In that handler add the logic for animation and visibility of the reset of the widgets. That how I would implement that.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do I need to listen for all events within GestureDetector ? or is there a single event that handle all type of Gesture events in flutter ?

Comment: Refer this link, it has code snippet as well.
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/handling-taps

Comment: You don't need a counter.  Just set a `Timer`.  When the `Timer` expires, hide the controls.  Whenever there's user input of some form, cancel the existing `Timer` and create a new one.